# How to get single array from multiple array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array like this

```
   var arr = [
                [ {"c": 1},{"d": 2} ],
                [ {"c": 2},{"d": 3} ]
             ]
```

I want to change into (by javascript only)

```
var newArr  = [{"c": 1},{"d": 2},{"c": 2},{"d": 3}]
```

I have tried this by map but not getting expected output .

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (your try with map)

Comment: you want to flatten the array of arrays into a single array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript [duplicate]

Comment: with a recursive function, testing if isArray the element of a array

Answer (score 10):

You can use `reduce()` and spread syntax.

```js
 var arr = [
  [ {"c": 1},{"d": 2} ],
  [ {"c": 2},{"d": 3} ]
]

var result = arr.reduce((r, e) => (r.push(...e), r), [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once, beautiful answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var arr = [[{ c: 1 }, { d: 2 }], [{ c: 2 }, { d: 3 }]],
    result = arr.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), []);

console.log(result)
```

ES5

```js
var arr = [[{ c: 1 }, { d: 2 }], [{ c: 2 }, { d: 3 }]],
    result = arr.reduce(function (r, a) { return r.concat(a); }, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain JavaScript you can do this using `Array.portotype.forEach`.

```js
var arr = [
                [ {"c": 1},{"d": 2} ],
                [ {"c": 2},{"d": 3} ]
             ];
             
var newArray = [];

arr.forEach(function(e){
 e.forEach(function(e1){
  newArray.push(e1);
 });
})

console.log(newArray);
```

Use this..